# Docker non-root user can't write external volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use `docker-compose` to run two docker containers, one for the server and another one for the MySql database. The server receives video files from an API endpoint and saves them into the `/app/media` folder.

However, it cannot access the `/media` folder which is an external volume I pointed to the local disk.

I already tried to create and change the owner for the folder manually (See the `Dockerfile` below).

I also use a similar method to mount the MySql database. It seems to read and write just fine.

The `Dockerfile` in my `server` folder:

```
FROM python:3.9.11
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    postgresql-client iputils-ping netcat
RUN groupadd app && useradd -m -g app app
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chown -R app:app /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/media
RUN chown -R app:app /app/media
RUN chmod go+w+x /app/media
USER app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 3000
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file for the project:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: ./server
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command:
      ['sh', './wait-for.sh', 'db:3306', '--', 'sh', './docker-entrypoint.sh']
    volumes:
      - ./media:/app/media

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.28-oracle
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db:
```

The error from the server after calling the POST API endpoint is:

```
PermissionError at /api/survey-responses/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/media/surveycore'
...
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/os.py, line 225, in makedirs
...
```

`surveycore` is the name of a Django app.

When I access the docker container from another terminal, I got:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 app  app    111 Mar 23 11:38 .dockerignore
-rw-rw-r-- 1 app  app    468 Mar 30 10:23 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x 1 app  app   4096 Mar 15 09:32 db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 app  app    172 Mar 23 10:50 docker-entrypoint.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 app  app    672 Mar 10 01:31 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Mar 30 09:58 media
-rw-rw-r-- 1 app  app   1502 Mar 23 09:57 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x 1 app  app   4096 Mar 15 10:25 surveycore
-rw-rw-r-- 1 app  app   3267 Mar 23 09:57 wait-for.sh
```

Everything else is assigned to the correct user `app`, except `media`.

The server was tested on a local machine. Nothing wrong with it.

I saw some suggestions about **accessing the container from another terminal as the root user, and giving the user right this way.** That seems like a hack to me, is there a proper way to config the docker file to fix the issue?